# how to set image in dialogbox in c++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, dialog

i have developing a  C++ Api project.

i will use dialogboxparam  to create  a dialogbox...

i done to create and set the textbox,labels and buttons...
its work fine...

now i want to add a image in the top of the dialogbox...

i did use this code in WM_INITDIALOG:

```
HBITMAP hImage= (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\BMA-Images\\login-header",IMAGE_BITMAP,LR_DEFAULTSIZE ,LR_DEFAULTSIZE ,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
            SendMessage(_hwnd,STM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)hImage);
```

But it didnt work...
Can anyone help to resolve this...
Thanks in advance
Sonu

Comment: There's no extension for your image. Is it really called "login-header"

Comment: `_hwnd` does refer to which window/control?

Comment: current dialogbox handle alk...

Comment: You should check if `hImage == NULL`, and, if so, call `GetLastError`. Also, `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` must be used in the 6th parameter.

Comment: Another one thing: `STM_SETIMAGE` should be sent to static controls only, not dialogs.

Comment: @Sonu: I suspected this. So please see Joulukuusi's comment on this. Also error checking never is a bad idea. Test return values!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the WM_PAINT for the window and paint the bitmap at that point (between the BeginPaint and EndPaint) calls

There is an MFC based example here:

http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/mfc_coding/113034/113034/how-do-i-set-a-background-picture-in-a-dialog-box-/

Comment: thanks for ur reply Goz,but i didnt use begin paint and end paint...without WM_PAINT,is other any way to achieve that?

Comment: @Sonu: What do you mean by not using BeginPaint/EndPaint?  To my knowledge there is no other way to do it ... but I may be wrong.

Comment: sorry about that I think your right. It sounds like there's no way of sending SETIMAGE message to dialog box controls. These are the messages related to dialogs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468826(v=vs.85).aspx , +1ve.

Comment: sorry sandun,that link was not helpful for me...actually what i need is if i press my button,i will invoke a dialogbox...how to set image for that dialog box?

Comment: @Sonu that was in MFC, you need to translate it to win32.

Comment: @sandundhammika: Does that mean my -1 ought not be there?

Comment: @Goz, No it's me -1 voted on your post. I finally realized that it should not belong here. Sorry for the inconvenience. I've add +1 now.

Answer (score 3):

When processing the `WM_INITDIALOG` message use `HWND hImageCtl = GetDlgItem(_hwnd, <image-control-resource-id>)` to get the handle of the image-control (this  assumes `_hwnd` is the handle to the dialog itself).

Then use `hImageCtl` to send the `STM_SETIMAGE` message to.

Comment: This also assumes that you've placed an image control in the dialog. It's important to note this since the question doesn't mention any associated control for the image.

Comment: Oook ... *scratching head* @MarkRansom

Answer (score 3):

This works for years, since Windows 98 for me:

```
//globals
HBRUSH hbr;
PAINTSTRUCT wcd;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam,
   LPARAM lParam )
{

   switch( msg ) {

   case WM_PAINT:
       if (GetUpdateRect(hWnd,r,0)) {   
           BeginPaint(hWnd,&wcd);
           if (wParam == NULL) FillRect(wcd.hdc,&wcd.rcPaint,hbr);
           EndPaint(hWnd,&wcd);         
       } 
        break;

      case WM_COMMAND:
///your code
   }
}



int  WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int Show)
{  
    ghInstance = hInstance;
    //Prepare brush for background
    hbr=CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BGROUND)));
///your code
    DialogBox(hInstance,"MAIN", NULL,(DLGPROC)MainWndProc);
///your code
    return(FALSE);
}
```

IDB_BGROUND - id of image resource, linked in.