# Trackbar control disappearing on resize

Tags: winapi, user-interface, c++11

I'm trying to write a WinAPI wrapper using C++11 but I've encountered a problem.

My tracksbars seem to go invisible whenever I resize the main window ( this problem does not occur with buttons/labels/progressbars/comboboxes/etc)

```
void Trackbar::Create(Window* parent)
{
    this->handle = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        TRACKBAR_CLASS
        nullptr,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBS_AUTOTICKS | TBS_ENABLESELRANGE | TBS_TRANSPARENTBKGND,
        170,
        150,
        100,
        50,
        parent->GetHandle(),
        0,
        GetModuleHandle(0),
        nullptr);

    if(!this->handle)
        ERRORMB();

    SendMessage(this->handle, TBM_SETRANGE, true, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, 100));
    SendMessage(this->handle, TBM_SETPAGESIZE, 0, 4);
    SendMessage(this->handle, TBM_SETSEL, false, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, 100));
    SendMessage(this->handle, TBM_SETPOS, true, 0);

}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does the parent window have the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style set?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: no, it only has WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW which doesn't have clipchilden.

Comment: Try setting it, it may help.

Comment: Just tried it, no difference.

Comment: What if you turn off the `TBS_TRANSPARENTBKGND` style?

Comment: that seems to work but I get a horrible black background and the slider leaves trails when moved (pic without and with transparent background http://i39.tinypic.com/2wodc00.png )

Comment: Managed to track down the background and trailing problem ( the cause being handling WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245169/creating-a-text-label-with-a-transparent-background-using-winapi] ). Any way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: The TBS_TRANSPARENTBKGND style probably doesn't work right because you don't implement WM_PRINTCLIENT in the parent.  The WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message probably doesn't work because you don't pay enough attention to the wparam.  Having trouble like this does encourage one to use a class library to take care of the endless small details of user32 programming ;)